# Not able to print data using Angular js 2

Tags: angularjs, service, components, mean-stack, ngfor

I'm not sure where I went wrong, created a**Mean Stack** app both server side and client. Server side works fine I'm able post, get and delete data from Table, but not able to display get data in **component.html** file. I have shared my component, services and html files, please find what's the error. If you need any another file I can share.

```js
This is ideas.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IdeaService } from "../idea.service";
import { Idea } from "../idea";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ideas',
  templateUrl:'./ideas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ideas.component.css'],
  providers: [IdeaService]
})
export class IdeasComponent implements OnInit {
  Ideas: Idea[];
  idea: Idea;
  Name: String;
  ideas: String;
  Comments: String

  constructor(private ideaService: IdeaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ideaService.getIdeas().subscribe(idea => this.idea = idea);
  }

}
```

```html
This ideas.component.html

<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let idea of idea">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{idea.Name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{idea.ideas}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{idea.Comments}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
This is idea.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Idea } from './idea';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class IdeaService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getIdeas() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/Demo_App/Home')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  addIdeas(newIdea) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/Demo_App/ideas', newIdea, { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

   deleteIdea(id){
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/Demo_App/idea/'+id)
    .map(res => res.json());
   }
}
```

```js
This is idea.ts

export class Idea{
    id?;
    Name:String;
    ideas:String;
    Comments:String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use idea instead of ideas in ngFor  in your html to display value

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let idea of ideas">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{idea.Name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{idea.ideas}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{idea.Comments}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can get more about displaying data in angular from below link
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: I have made some changes. But even now i'm facing same issue

Comment: Write like this in your ngFor let idea of ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "idea" instead of "ideas" inside the loop
Your problem is that in subscribe you are overwriting your idea object. You are not pushing anything into the array.

Changes you need to make:

ideas.component.ts

```
ideasArray: Idea[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.ideaService.getIdeas().subscribe(idea => 
                                          {this.idea = idea;
                                            if(idea){ 
                                             this.ideasArray.push(idea);});
}
```

ideas.component.html

```
<div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let idea of ideasArray">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          {{idea.Name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          {{idea.ideas}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          {{idea.Comments}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Added idea class

Comment: I would assume,that changing "ideas" to "idea" didn't help?